# Relocate working copy to new SVN repository not working in Netbeans

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

My locally installed SVN repository was relocated & is no longer available at the previous location. Infact the previous path is even no longer valid.

I tried to move the working directory in Netbeans this way:

> **Project Name-> Subversion-> Working Copy-> Relocate...**

But I believe due to previous path no longer valid it does not allow to me relocate the repository for this working copy. (When I try to submit the relocate repository dialog in netbeans, the submit button just does not work)

**How do I relocate the repository for my working copy ? Other ways ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try to complete this task using command-line client, run the command `svn relocate <URL>`. Does it work? If it does not, then what does it say in the output?

If it works, then it's interesting what actions you perform in Netbeans. What errors do you get?

Comment: Thanks!I did came across this earlier...but haven't yet tried out,  Don't I need to specify path of my working directory in that command ?? how would it know otherwise what to modify ? Also, before I try this out, could clarify what exactly this does, modifies .svn folders inside working directory or does modifications to new repository itself ?

Comment: Also important thing, that working copy has been modified after last commit to repository, so those changes must survive after this relocation.

Comment: @user01 if you use `svn relocate` then your your working copy will be relocated or not. If not -- your changes are still safe and you can try another actions.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to invoke Relocate command in Netbeans IDE 8.2 I had error: 
"svn: E155019: Cannot relocate '..../trunk' as it is not the root of a working copy"
I run the Relocate command using the TortoiseSvn client and it did the job.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the .svn folder in the project folder, close the project, restarted IDE, re open project, and import to new repo.